# What do R-squared values and percentage error indicate about the method of an experiment?

Tags: error-analysis, experimental-technique

In an experiment, I plotted the data on a graph, and the R-squared value was 0.9996. I then calculated the percentage error, which was 1.47%. I know a high R-squared value indicates low random error, and a low percentage error indicates a low systematic error, but how does this relate to the method of this experiment? E.g., does low systematic error indicate an appropriate method, and a low random error indicate appropriate use of instruments?

Comment: Could you give a reference/definition for this R-squared value?

Comment: @flippiefanus A measure of how close the data points are to the line of best fit

Comment: @flippiefanus Have a look at http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/regression-analysis-how-do-i-interpret-r-squared-and-assess-the-goodness-of-fit and http://archive.bio.ed.ac.uk/jdeacon/statistics/tress11.html

Comment: *"I know a high R-squared value indicates low random error, and a low percentage error indicates a low systematic error"* Both of these statements are only rules of thumb: good for many common cases, but not to be relied upon as definitive. And that's before we even get into the question of why we are teaching percentage error in *science* classes.